# PHP - FB photo/video upload issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload

I'm working on a web site that has to upload some videos and photos on my personal FB page.

I'm using the PHP SDK v4, and I registered my test App on FB (called CountLikes). Trying and trying again, I finally made a simple post on my wall, so at the moment I want to upload an image on my profile.

I copied the code written here, changing filename and path: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/4.0.0

I don't get any error message, but the code is not working fine. When I check on my profile I see that there is a new album called "CountLikes Album", but inside there is no photo.

The Access Token I use has all the possible permission (I will select the right ones when I will do this upload).

I post here the code I written (APPID, APPSECRET and TOKEN are written correctly in the original code): could you help me?

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'Z:/Sito/FB/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APPID','APPSECRET');
FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);
$session = new FacebookSession('TOKEN');
if($session) 
{
  try 
  {
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
    'source' => new CURLFile('Z:\Sito\FB\test.jpg', 'image/png'),
    'message' => 'User provided message'
  )
))->execute()->getGraphObject();
echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
  } 
   catch(FacebookRequestException $e) 
   {
echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using your own app, then the new album should not be named “Graph API Explorer”, it should have the name of your own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be with this line:

```
'source' => new CURLFile('Z:\Sito\FB\test.jpg', 'image/png'),
```

You are setting the type as `png` and uploading `jpg`. Update that and see if it works.

Comment: Dear Bangdel, thank you for your suggest.
I tried editing the line with "jpg" and also "jpeg", but it didn't worked.

Comment: Dear Bangdel, it finally worked! :)

I tried also with this line for the video upload and now everything work fine!

'source' => new CURLFile('Z:\Sito\FB\test.mp4', 'video/mp4')

Thank you again, you're my hero!